# Resolving a sub directory to a Heroku app via .htaccess?

Tags: apache, heroku, dns, http-proxy, mediatemple

I use a Media Temple Grid Service solution for hosting. I currently have a Heroku app which I serve via `blog.domain.com` using a `CNAME` record.

I'm trying to have the sub-directory `domain.com/blog` resolve to the Heroku app instead. I don't want the header to change, so I'm not looking for a redirect I believe.

I've attempted a couple of snippets for .htaccess files which have not worked for me. Can anyone recommend some tips to have this work?

It seems a proxy pass would work from the research I've done, but I can't figure out where or how to set it up given my GS folder structure.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.